# AlertDialog windows size doesn't match layout

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-constraintlayout

I have some problems with my AlertDialog. AlertDialog is show after I click ImageButton and the problem is size of AlertDialog window - it doesn't match to layout inside which causes the view to be cut off. Tried everything i've found here and no effects.

AlertDialog.xml code

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/price"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/price"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/greater_than"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/greater_than"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/price"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/less_than"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/less_than"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/price" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/greater_than_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/greater_than"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/greater_than"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/greater_than" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/less_than_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/less_than"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/less_than"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/less_than" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/notification_checkBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/alaram_notification"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/less_than_edit" />
```

and my AlertBuilder code

```
@Override
        public void alarmOnClick(View v, int position) {
                View prompt = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupdialog, null);
                EditText biggerThanEdit = prompt.findViewById(R.id.greater_than_edit);
                EditText lessThanEdit = prompt.findViewById(R.id.less_than_edit);
                TextView biggerThan = prompt.findViewById(R.id.greater_than);
                TextView lessThan = prompt.findViewById(R.id.less_than);
                CheckBox notificationCheckBox = prompt.findViewById(R.id.notification_checkBox);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
                        .setView(prompt)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.set_alarm))
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        // Log.d("mainactivity "," dialog box  cancel pasrd-------- \n");
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.show();
        }
```

this is screen from AVD with android 8. 
[image: alertDialog_window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done. I have not found a solution to my problem anywhere, so i post it here and hope it will help someone.

styles.xml

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

dialoglayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/price"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/greater_than"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/greater_than"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/price"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/less_than"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/less_than"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/price"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/price" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/greater_than_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/greater_than"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/greater_than" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/less_than_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/less_than"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/less_than" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/notification_checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/alaram_notification"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/less_than_edit"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/less_than_edit" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my alertdialog builder

```
@Override
        public void alarmOnClick(View v, int position) {
                View prompt = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupdialog, null);
                EditText biggerThanEdit = prompt.findViewById(R.id.greater_than_edit);
                EditText lessThanEdit = prompt.findViewById(R.id.less_than_edit);
                TextView biggerThan = prompt.findViewById(R.id.greater_than);
                TextView lessThan = prompt.findViewById(R.id.less_than);
                CheckBox notificationCheckBox = prompt.findViewById(R.id.notification_checkBox);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme)
                        .setView(prompt)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.set_alarm) + " " + mData.get(position).getCryptoCurrency() + "/" + mData.get(position).getFiatCurrency())
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        // Log.d("mainactivity "," dialog box  cancel pasrd-------- \n");
                    }
                });
                alertDialogBuilder.show();
        }
```

May the Force be with you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Remove

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout...
```

tag and replace the whole xml with `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Looks like it's working, but I don't remove ContraintLayout, only add RelativeLayout above it and works perfectly. I tried relativelayout earlier and it's doesn't work don't know why. Edit question and add valid layout file which works for me.